# NSFetchRequest in Core Data

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am having a very hard time understanding what needs to be included in the Children Views in order to perform a fetch request and display the results in a table view when using Core Data. All the examples I have found are either only one layer deep (Random Dates), using the Root View Controller which always works, or using several view controllers with pictures and other attributes (Recipes) that make it confusing for me to follow.

An example of what I am looking for would be an Entity with three attributes. The entity is album and the three attributes are albumTitle, albumArtist and yearRecorded.

Now in my Navigation app my Root View Controller has three rows to choose from not using the Entity or Core Data at all. The three choices are "Title", "Artist" and "Year". When you click on one of the three rows it will push a new view controller and list all of the appropriate attributes in a new table view.

I believe it should be very simple and not require too much code but I can't get a handle on it. Any explanations or sample code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a fetch request with no predicates to get all the objects from your Core Data store, so, you'll have an array of songs.

Than you just call, for example, `[fetchedSongs valueForKeyPath:@"artist"];` to get an arry of artist and add it as a source to your tableview.

Comment: So are you saying I leave the fetch request in my Root View Controller even though I don't use it there to grab everything and then query each attribute and send it to the next view controller?

Comment: I'm still not getting the syntax or layout to make it happen. I'm adding my code from my RootViewController and my FolderListViewController. I used the album reference earlier because I thought it would be easier to explain. Below is my current code. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do I add the fetchedSongs you wrote above to my RootViewController or my SubViewController? Does that line automatically make an array called fetchedSongs for me to use in my cellForRowAtIndexPath in the Subview? If I can just see this work once I know I will get understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: No, fetchedSongs are the song you get from the fetch request. Then you get the albums and atrists using the method above

Comment: Do you know why in most of the Apple examples they just do entity.attribute like book.title but when I try similar code it never works? Folder *folder = [__fetchedResultsController   objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];                      cell.textLabel.text = folder.folderName;